# Display jQuery Accordion when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

All.

I'm working on a long manual, and each section is an accordion that displays when clicked. This is the code for it:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

So in total I have 24 sections (each is an accordion).

I'm trying to insert links in one of the sections to point to a different section. This is what they look like right now:

```
  <li><a href="#source1">How to configure Source 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#source2">How to configure Source 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#source3">How to configure Source 3</a></li>
```

The links currently redirect you to the requested section (identified by id="source1", "source2" and "source3" respectively. However, the accordion doesn't open up. The link takes you to the section, but the accordion remains closed.

Is there any way I can get that accordion to open up when the link is clicked? I figured I would need an onclick function, but I'm not entirely sure of how to write it.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: According with the **jQuery UI Accordion API** (http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) I don't found any method to activate programatically a custom tab. So or you can make manually or you can make the accordion by another way or plugin.

Comment: not sure about jquery ui as we gave it up long time ago, but with ex. semantic ui you have an api to expand or collapse any of the accordions, that way you can expand it first and then use normal anchor or just scroll to accordion, if there is no api you can make it ugly way and simpy call a click() on the accordion :)\

Comment: Adding codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gayPJE?editors=100. As you can see, clicking on the link highlights the desired section but doesn't expand it. Any ideas?

Comment: that codepen id though ^_^

Comment: I know. Supposed to be random :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 <li><a href="#dropbox" onclick="$('#dropbox').click()">How to configure Dropbox</a></li>
 <li><a href="#gdrive" onclick="$('#gdrive').click()">How to configure Google Drive</a></li>
 <li><a href="#sserver" onclick="$('#sserver').click()">How to configure SharePoint</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Accordion API](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) not provide any functionality for this.

My try Not sure but i think this will work..

```
  $("#goToSecondSection").click(function(){//your link

             $("#yourSelector").accordion('option', 'active' , 1);//1,2,3,.. put accordingly 

       });
```

Comment: Tried that. That takes me to the Header/section, it just doesn't open up the accordion. Any thoughts?

Comment: Good you got your answer and that was our objective :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not comfortable with codepen so took all your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpqbpuv8/), made changes and it works:

Relevant section of code is:

```
<a href="#dropbox" onclick='$("#dropbox").click();'>How to configure Dropbox3</a>
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you! Never worked w/JSFiddle before, always relied on Codepen. Thx!